# Compiling/Using MySQL Connector/C++ with MinGW

Tags: c++, mysql, compiler-construction, mingw

Well, I guess the title sums it up pretty well. The connector comes with Visual Studio libraries and dlls. There is also a source tar available which doesn't compile.

Comment: errors about various visual studio-specific #pragma preprocessor definitions and some more let me check it out again...

Comment: You have to build the code as if you're building it until Unix/Linux with the appropriate #defines etc, otherwise you'll probably get all sorts of funky errors.