# C++ - MySQL client libraries - link statically with MinGW?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, static-libraries

I want to develop a C++ application that uses a remote MySQL server. I believe that to do this, I need the MySQL client libraries.

I use MinGW to compile, and I need the .exe to be stand alone, so it needs to be static.

Is it even possible? I've tried linking with the static mysqlclient.lib that is supplied with the community download but it doesn't appear to work with MinGW, I get undefined reference errors such as `undefined reference to 'mysql_init@4'`.

If it is possible, someone please explain how, I have searched everywhere and haven't found a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling/Using MySQL Connector/C++ with MinGW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419876/compiling-using-mysql-connector-c-with-mingw)

Comment: _statically_ link. Also, I'm not talking about the connector, I mean the MySQL libs. I think there is a difference.

Comment: Oops. My bad. The user comments at the bottom of this documentation page has info on using MySQL in MinGW: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/building-clients.html

Comment: @EmileCormier: Nice source, but unfortunately my difficulty is not getting it to work with MinGW, it's getting it to work _statically_ with MinGW.

Comment: did you manage to achieve this? I'm trying this with Linux!

Comment: @Stefano: Sorry for not saying so, but I instead wrote a PHP interface on the web that does all the MySQL stuff for me. On the desktop side, I simply connect to the interface with the URL params that I want - much simpler (and safer, in case one were to run `strings` on the executable and would find the user and password).

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm still finding a way to statically link MySQL library to another database layer library.